# I installed mingw32-pthreads-w32 but I still cannot compile std::mutex

Tags: c++, g++, mingw

According to advice here on stack overflow, I installed mingw32 pthread package:

[image: image description]

But I still cannot compile code using C++11 multithreading:

```
 error: 'mutex' in namespace 'std' does not name a type
```

I use makefile which I execute using mingw32-make and that uses `g++` which is located at `C:\MinGW\bin\g++.exe`.

G++ version: `g++.exe (GCC) 5.3.0`
Mingw32 make version: `GNU Make 3.82.90`, `Built for i686-pc-mingw32`

I used the `-M` option to generate list of used headers and this is what I've got:

```
 c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\thread \
 c:\mingw\lib\gcc\mingw32\5.3.0\include\c++\mutex \
```

I am not even sure if these are the correct headers.

What could be wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Show the code you used just so we know you didn't forget `#include <mutex>`. Also posting the result of `g++ --version` will probably be of use. And how the compiler is being invoked.

Comment: No I didn't forget to include mutex, the code compiles just fine and works on linux. It also compiles on windows when I compile with Qt Creator which carries it's own release of MinGW.

Comment: I suggest you get MinGW64: https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/ . The original MinGW wasn't maintained in a long time. Qt creator comes with MinGW64(it's not their own release). You can use the mingw from there(Qt) or download what I gave you. For std threads to work, you'll need posix threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC for Windows comes with two thread model: win32 and posix. Only posix thread model has support for standard multi-threading library.

To check that, try running `g++ -v`. If you do not see `--enable-thread=posix`, that means your compiler suite does not support standard multi-threading library.

You can download Mingw64 GCC from https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/ , they are built with `--enable-thread=posix`.

Note that even though `--enable-thread=posix` means you can use standard multi-threading library, the implementation much slower than directly using Win32 API like `CreateThread`. This is because for GCC, `std::thread` etc are implemented on top of `gthread`, `gthread` are implemented based on `pthread`. Because Windows does not support `pthread`, Mingw64 team implement `pthread` with Win32 API. You can see that there is quite a lot of abstraction debt you need to pay.

If performance is important for you, you might not want to use it. You also need to distribute `winpthread.dll` to end-user because static link won't work.

If you want your code to work in all platform, it is fine to use it.

Comment: Thanks for such detailed explanation!